# Change dictionary value in list of dictionaries

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
{
  "__class": "Tape",
  "Clips": [
    {
      "__class": "MotionClip",
      "Id": 4280596098,
      "TrackId": 4094799440,
      "IsActive": 1,
      "StartTime": 180,
      "Duration": 48,
      "ClassifierPath": "world\/maps\/error\/timeline\/moves\/error_intro_walk.msm",
      "GoldMove": 0,
      "CoachId": 0,
      "MoveType": 0,
   {
      "__class": "MotionClip",
      "Id": 2393481294,
      "TrackId": 4094799440,
      "IsActive": 1,
      "StartTime": 372,
      "Duration": 48,
      "ClassifierPath": "world\/maps\/error\/timeline\/moves\/error_ve_opening.msm",
      "GoldMove": 0,
      "CoachId": 0,
      "MoveType": 0,
...
```

This is a snippet of json file in which I want to change the ways number are presented. For example I want 1 written as 00000001, 48 as 00000048, 0 as 00000000. So all numbers in whole json file are written as I said before. They can be written as strings.
I don't know how to start because I have list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data actually looks like this -

```
main_dict = {
  "__class": "Tape",
  "Clips": [
    {
      "__class": "MotionClip",
      "Id": 4280596098,
      "TrackId": 4094799440,
      "IsActive": 1,
      "StartTime": 180,
      "Duration": 48,
      "ClassifierPath": "world\/maps\/error\/timeline\/moves\/error_intro_walk.msm",
      "GoldMove": 0,
      "CoachId": 0,
      "MoveType": 0,
   },
   {
      "__class": "MotionClip",
      "Id": 2393481294,
      "TrackId": 4094799440,
      "IsActive": 1,
      "StartTime": 372,
      "Duration": 48,
      "ClassifierPath": "world\/maps\/error\/timeline\/moves\/error_ve_opening.msm",
      "GoldMove": 0,
      "CoachId": 0,
      "MoveType": 0,
   }
  ]
}
```

You can do the following -

```
#Accessing a specific key in a dict, in this case Clips (list of dicts)
list_dicts = main_dict.get('Clips')  

#Function to fix/edit specific values in the list of dict based on what key they belong to
def fix_value(k,v):

    if k=='Duration':
        return '00000'+str(v)

    #Add more elseif in between with various things you wanna handle 

    else:
        return v

#Iterating over each key, value in each dict in list of dicts and applying above function on the values

[{k:fix_value(k,v) for k,v in i.items()} for i in list_dicts]
```

Result -

```
[{'__class': 'MotionClip',
  'Id': 4280596098,
  'TrackId': 4094799440,
  'IsActive': 1,
  'StartTime': 180,
  'Duration': '0000048',
  'ClassifierPath': 'world\\/maps\\/error\\/timeline\\/moves\\/error_intro_walk.msm',
  'GoldMove': 0,
  'CoachId': 0,
  'MoveType': 0},
 {'__class': 'MotionClip',
  'Id': 2393481294,
  'TrackId': 4094799440,
  'IsActive': 1,
  'StartTime': 372,
  'Duration': '0000048',
  'ClassifierPath': 'world\\/maps\\/error\\/timeline\\/moves\\/error_ve_opening.msm',
  'GoldMove': 0,
  'CoachId': 0,
  'MoveType': 0}]
```

Comment: `data=[{k:fix_value(k,v) for k,v in i.items()} for i in list_dicts] 
s = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
print(re.sub('(\d+)', lambda i: hex(int(i.group(0))),s))`

Two last lines are supposed to convert all numbers to hex. They do, but I don't get it in format I want.

They are printed as I even didn't apply your solution. I get same result using just two last lines of code.

Comment: `[{"__class": "MotionClip", "Id": 0xff24b682, "TrackId": 0xf411ae50, "IsActive": "0x1", "StartTime": 0xb4, "Duration": 0x30, "ClassifierPath": "world/maps/error/timeline/moves/error_intro_walk.msm", "GoldMove": 0x0, "CoachId": 0x0, "MoveType": 0x0}, {"__class": "MotionClip", "Id": 0x8ea9a04e, "TrackId": 0xf411ae50, "IsActive": "0x1", "StartTime": 0x174, "Duration": 0x30, "ClassifierPath": "world/maps/error/timeline/moves/error_ve_opening.msm", "GoldMove": 0x0, "CoachId": 0x0, "MoveType": 0x0}`